# Переадресация вызова из одной функции в другую

Tags: javascript

```
function f() {
    g.apply(null, arguments);
}

function g(a, b, c) {
    alert( a + b + c );
}

f(1, 2, 3); // 6
```

Почему срабатывает данный код? Вызываем функцию `g` в контексте NULL. Иными словами вызываем `g` как метод объекта `NULL`. О как?

Comment: @Decode, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Нет. Вы не вызываете функцию как метод объекта null. Вы вызываете функцию с контекстом null. Контекст - это просто некое значение, доступное в функции через ключевое слово this и быть там может что угодно.Вот одно из самых популярных применений:

```
function test (a,b,c) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); // вызываем метод slice, "заточенный" под массивы, для массиво-подобного объекта arguments. Так часто приводят объект arguments к массиву
  console.log(Array.isArray(args));
  console.log(Array.isArray(arguments));
};
```

Comment: Но почему тогда Флэнаган так пишет, цитата из его книги:

"Методы call() и apply() позволяют выполнять косвенный вызов функции, как если бы она была методом некоторого другого объекта. Первым аргументом обоим методам, call() и apply(), передается объект, относительно которого вызывается функция; этот аргумент определяет контекст вызова и становится значением ключевого слова this в теле функции."

И приводится вот такой пример:

f.apply(o);

o.m = f; // Временно сделать f методом o.
o.m(); // Вызывать его без аргументов.
delete o.m; // Удалить временный метод.

Это вообще меня сбивает с толку.

Answer (score 0):

Если контекст `null` или `undefined` - значит вызывается без контекста (в non-strict режиме, `this` не может быть `null`, поэтому `this` заменяется глобальным контекстом).

Comment: А если в контексте полный бред? http://jsfiddle.net/s7sfLs8e/

Comment: @Decode, просто нужно понять, что это не то место, где происходит поиск функции, а где функция берёт данные. т.е. http://jsfiddle.net/mn43m0p0/ . т.е. мы делаем один метод который умеет работать с данными, а потом передаем ему данные в зависимости от контекста.

Comment: @stck, я понял. В моем примере, который я привел, this вообще никак не используется, т.е. функция g при вызове не ссылается ни на какой объект. Но чтобы передать в g массиво-подобный объект arguments — нужно вызвать g через метод apply.

Вызов f.apply(this, 1, 2, 3) — это тоже самое, что и вызов f(1,2,3), но с явным указанием this.

Comment: @Decode, если я правильно понял цель, то Вам нужно использовать `f.apply([1,2,3])` и внутри `f` работать с объектом `this`, либо же `f([1,2,3])`, где `f` - `function f(x)`, `x` - объект. Еще есть динамический разбор аргументов - с помощью объекта `arguments` внутри `function`, но такой подход не есть хороший тон.

Comment: @stck, да не, никакой цели нет. Просто пытался разобраться с методами call/apply. Флэнаган сбил меня с толку.